# Any issues with the following in-place reverse function?

Tags: c, algorithm

I wrote this following in-place reverse function and it works fine.

However, when I googled for a solution, I found plethora of more complex solutions but nothing this simple. Will the following not work for certain inputs or has some performance issues?

```
void reverse(char* str) {
    int n = strlen(str);
    char temp;

    for (int i=0; i<n/2; i++) {
        temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[n-i-1];
        str[n-i-1] = temp;
    }
}

int main() {
    char input[] = "Reverse Me!";
    reverse(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could try posting on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This task is often given to new programmers, which might explain why there are a lot of bad solutions around

Comment: str could be not null terminated, in which case strlen fails.

Comment: @Ant Then it's not a string.

Comment: FWIW I've been writing C for 12 years and I'd never have thought of using your /2 solution (instead I'd allocate a new buffer and iterate the string backward to fill it).  Your solution is awesome, it'd just never have occurred to me.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin That's just a pointer to char though.

Comment: @Ant Yes, true enough.

Comment: To say the somewhat obvious, unicode characters won't work there.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This may *work correctly* on your system; however, `strlen` returns `size_t`, which might have a greater precision than `int`, resulting in only a part (or none?) of the actual string being reversed. That's an easy fix: Declare `n` as a `size_t` instead of an `int`.

Your solution could be simpler, if you were to decrease `n` each iteration while you're increasing `x`. Then you wouldn't need as much of the subtraction logic, or *any* of the division logic.

```
void reverse(char *str) {
    for (size_t x = 0, y = strlen(str); y --> x; x++) {
        char temp = str[x];
        str[x] = str[y];
        str[y] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Less obfuscated as   `y-- > x`

Comment: @MattMcNabb That's the [goes to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator) operator ;)

Comment: Say, what is that "-->" operator you have there??

Comment: @MattMcNabb Correct! You've won Jeopardy! Your prize is an up-vote!

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no issues with your code. It will work perfectly in any situation with ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

@Rahat Mahbub is right about `size_t`. On many 64 bit machines, your algorithm will fail for strings 2^31 in length or longer. Using `size_t` will prevent that.

But the main problem is the complexity. A clearer code is something like:

```
void reverse(char *str) {
  if (*p == '\0') return;
  for (size_t i = 0, j = strlen(str) - 1; i < j; ++i, --j) {
    char tmp = str[i]; 
    str[i] = str[j]; 
    str[j] = tmp;
  }
}
```

In words, place `i` at the start of the string and `j` at the end. Swap characters they index and move both toward the middle of until they touch.

With pointers, it's even a bit more succinct:

```
void reverse(char *p) {
  if (*p == '\0') return;
  for (char *q = p + (strlen(p) - 1); p < q; ++p, --q) {
    char tmp = *p; 
    *p = *q; 
    *q = tmp;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately as @chux pointed out, you need the `if` or some other footwork to avoid computing `q = p - 1` on empty input, which is not a valid pointer. In the indexed version, you need it because `size_t` is an unsigned type; it has no -1 value.

Comment: I too prefer indices over pointer arithmetic,yet `j = strlen("") - 1; i < j` remains a problem as it becomes `i < SIZE_MAX`.  "So other may dream 2017"